# Mostrar local notification con xamarin forms con la app cerrada

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Con esta línea de código :

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body");
```

y el plugin https://github.com/edsnider/localnotificationsplugin  puedo mostrar una local notification en xamarin forms. Sin embargo necesito poder mostrarla cuando la aplicación esta cerrada. Como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que para este escenario es necesario utilizar Push notifications ya que en ambas plataformas tanto android como iOS al cerrar la aplicación tu código no se ejecutara.

Te recomiendo utilizar Firebase que te permite enviar para iOS y Android

[Documentación de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=es)

También te dejo este tutorial para lograrlo en Xamarin Forms Android
[Android Xamarin Forms](https://xamarinlatino.com/xamarin-forms-firebase-cloud-messaging-android-setup-8b4eef80fd28)

[iOS Xamarin Forms FCM](https://xamarinlatino.com/xamarin-forms-firebase-cloud-messaging-ios-setup-1961a91d4055)

Comment: podrías dejar un ejemplo en código? en caso de que los enlaces dejaran de funcionar, ya que colocar enlaces externos así sin más se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Pues comento que implemente mi propio servicio de push notifications sin necesidad de usar firebase ni nada de eso.